# Why is my APIs not working after building the APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api

I encountered an issue after building my project in Android Studio and successfully generating the APK. Upon installing the app, I noticed that the APIs I'm utilizing, specifically Google APIs, aren't functioning as expected.

I've followed the usual procedures for integrating these APIs into my Android app, including obtaining the necessary API keys, ensuring proper permissions in the manifest file, and configuring the API client appropriately.

Despite this, when the app is installed and running, the expected functionality tied to the Google APIs doesn't seem to be working. I've double-checked the API key integration and the code implementation for accessing these APIs, yet I'm still facing this issue.

Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on troubleshooting steps to identify the root cause of this problem? Additionally, are there any common pitfalls or less-obvious configurations that might affect the proper functioning of Google APIs within an Android app after deployment?

Any insights or assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: This is where I build my apk]

I am currently using proguard, it seems that minify is set to false

[image]

Comment: are you using proguard for releasing? maybe you are obfuscating some code (libs, dependencies), which shouldn't be...

Comment: @Chichi Add `@keep` notation to your Model, POJO, Request class, and API Interfaces to prevent minifying.

Comment: I am using proguard and it seems that minify is set to false. Is there any configurations should I do to prevent the problem?